# Computing a matrix out of a 'flat table'

Tags: r, associations, sparse-matrix

I'm new to stackoverflow and to datascience. Right now i've got a project where i want to perform a association rule analysis. I've got some troubles with making the matrix for the analysis. My data is looking like this:

column 1: receiptnumber, column 2: brand, column 3: bought or not.

I would like to get a matrix whereby the receiptnumbers are the rows, and the brands are the columns. I've to say that not every receiptnumber has all the brands covert.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) along with the expected output

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and of course how to give [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is as simple as creating a table. I'll provide a MWE:

```
data <- data.frame(receiptnumber = c('1', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
                   brand = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

print(data)

#   receiptnumber brand
# 1             1     A
# 2             1     A
# 3             2     B
# 4             3     C
# 5             4     D

tabData <- table(data$receiptnumber, data$brand)

print(tabData)

#   A B C D
# 1 2 0 0 0
# 2 0 1 0 0
# 3 0 0 1 0
# 4 0 0 0 1
```

Normal indexing still works

```
tabData[1,3]

# 0
```

Comment: Hi Frost maggot, I've tried the thing you mentioned above. When i tried to run it Rstudio gave the following error: "cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 gb. When i saw this happening i've tried to make a small subset (total of 791 observations) and ran it again. Rstudio gave the same error, so I think there is another problem but i can't find which. It should be fairly easy for R to make a matrix with so few datapoints right? Do you have any idea how I can solve this? Thanks for your help by the way, it is nice for a starter with R programming to aks certain experienced people about these probs